# Get class of parameterized class in Kotlin

Tags: java, generics, kotlin

I need to send `Class` as parameter of a function. The problem is that the class which I want to send is a parametrized class:

```
class Animal<T> {
   ...
}
```

Code below produces a compilation error:

```
someFunction(Animal<String>::class.java)
```

Declaration of `someFunction` in Java:

```
public <T> someFunction(Class<T> someClass) {
    ...
}
```

Am I able to send parametrized class to `someFunction`?

Comment: I'm not versed in Kotlin but I believe it suffers from _type-erasure_ just like Java.

Comment: Why you can't just do `someFunction(Animal::class.java)` ?

Comment: @Sergey Unfortunately it produces compilation error also.